# How do you translate a row of infinitive words in Esperanto?

Tags: translation, infinitive

The most obvious answer would be to just make a row of infinitive Esperanto words, but I wonder if you can not introduce more explicit relations.

Here is an example from [Consecutive infinitives on English Language & Usage Stack Exchange](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/44050/consecutive-infinitives)

> The witness plans to refuse to testify.

That in a first approach could be translated as:

> La spektanto[1] planas rifuzi atesti.

But this seems rather unusual to me as Esperanto construction, and I'm not sure it's even grammatically acceptable. So I would probably go with something like:

> La spektanto planas refuzadon de atestado.

The above link give example with more infinitive verbs in a row, like *The witness refuses to consider to agree to testify to help to free*,  so I wonder how I would translate such a sentence. Could I use a simple row of infinitive verbs in Esperanto too?

[1] aŭ atestanto sed tio ne gravas por la nuna demando.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You would just put many infinitives one after the other, as you suggested at first. This is grammatically correct and perfectly acceptable. Thus

> La spektanto planas rifuzi atesti.

is completely fine. This is also what I would naturally say. In tekstaro there are plenty of examples of [double infinitives](http://tekstaro.com/?s=5a8a93f60a950) (for some reason the link may not work, but search `\b\LI{3,}i\b \b\LI{3,}i\b` on [tekstaro](http://tekstaro.com)). Here is one with *rifuzi* in particular:

> Li ne povas (…) rifuzi paroli, ĉar la publiko ne plaĉas al li.

—*Retoriko*

For your last sentence you would indeed just get a row of infinitives, but note that for *to help* you would actually add *por*, because it is a goal (a good indication of this is that you can replace ‘to help’  with ‘in order to help’):

> La spektanto rifuzas konsideri konsenti atesti por helpi liberigi la akuziton.